# Can only connect once to WCF service over TCP

Tags: c#, wcf

A WCF service is exposed over a net.tcp binding. This works fine as long as the connection remains active. After a disconnect, the client cannot connect to the service anymore. What could case this problem?

Comment: Can you share the code you have to create your connection. Do you have your code to connect within a using{} clause?

Comment: Will share it. Could it be that only one client can connect at the same time?

Comment: I think the reason might be that the proxy didn't close properly when you disconnected. So the **using()** method mentioned in the above comment is valid.